# Get data from different tables in different databases

Tags: sql, database

I need to get the **data from different tables in different databases**.
Here are the columns I need to get the data: *Orgname, Name, Amount of Users, Amount of Active Users, Usage clic - Lifetime, Usage clic- 30 days, Usage clic - 1 day, Usage Trend, Expiry Date*.

The "usage trend" column is filled up manually with arrows.

I have the databases:

- "A" which lists the tables "organization" and "user"
- "B" which lists the table "request"

The tables:

- "organization" lists the columns: orgname, full_name, is_active
- "user" lists the columns: username, firstname, lastname, email, is_active, orgname, expiry_date
- "request" lists the columns: username, orgname, time, request_count

Here's my beginning of SQL query:

```
SELECT user.orgname, COUNT(DISTINCT user.username), COUNT(DISTINCT user.is_active), COUNT(request.projects_priced_count)
FROM prod_virida_auth.user
INNER JOIN prod_virida_pricing.request ON request.orgname = user.orgname 
GROUP BY orgname 
ORDER BY orgname;
UNION
SELECT count(request.projects_priced_count) AS count 
FROM prod_virida_pricing.request 
WHERE projects_priced_count = :refid AND BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND NOW();
```

It gives the good results for the first 2 columns, but not for the active users which lists only few users whereas I'm expecting more...

I use MySQL on PHPMYADMIN.
I don't really know about the other SELECT queries I should write to get all my report...

I have the error : "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':refid AND BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND NOW() LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3"

Please help :)

Comment: Please post the error as text. Do you have the right to SELECT on both database and tables? Please post the table structure. What RDBMS are your using. Please complete your question.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: provide much more details about your table such as the full column names

Comment: Ok I've updated my post! :)